# How to pass ArrayList item to body of http request (post) in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

**I hava a ArrayList where storing data from my API** `List<GetTestFeeMap> reponseArray =[];   // Storing API response`

**Then Adding data to my Arraylist** ➡ `reponseArray.add(getTestFeeObj!);`

Now trying to get each `encTestId`. But its just give the first value only (obviously). **I want to pass all the `encTestId`(to http body) which is possibly in my List (*separated by comma*.)**

```
 getTestFeeObj=GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(jsonResponse);
              for (var i = 0; i < reponseArray.length; i++) {
                    eNcTestIdInList=(reponseArray[i].encTestId)!;
                    }
```

Then passing to my body of http request

```
  body: ({

        'EncDoctorId'   : eNcTestIdInList,
     )}
```

Example of correct body in postman

```
{
"EncDoctorId": "I3uXyzcuDZf21SSe5fHnSQ==,7Ch2aVnhokZtRWyJtuDA/A==",   // 2 encTestId 
}
```

I hope you understood my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
eNcTestIdInList+=(reponseArray[i].encTestId);
if (i < reponseArray.length -1) eNcTestIdInList+= ",";
```

Comment: its showing `The method  'add' isn't defined for the type 'String'.` I put in like this inside forloop ` eNcTestIdInList=eNcTestIdInList.add(reponseArray[i].encTestId);`

Comment: Oh, didn't realize it was a string, try now I edited my answer

Comment: Api response  failed `{"Status":"0","Message":"Wrong operation","EncBookingId":null}` I belive its because its adding up the String `(A+b)= AB`. Insted it should separated with `comma(,)` as in my body example `"EncDoctorId": "I3uXyzcuDZf21SSe5fHnSQ==,7Ch2aVnhokZtRWyJtuDA/A==",`

Comment: I print it `eNcTestIdInList` in my console: `I3uXyzcuDZf21SSe5fHnSQ==I3uXyzcuDZf21SSe5fHnSQ==7Ch2aVnhokZtRWyJtuDA/A==`  its adding up whole string . How can I separate them with comma?